# Generic way of handling DBNull

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I have a lot of this type of logic in my code when using the SqlDataReader
Is there a cleaner more generic way to handle this?

```
 if (reader["VisitingAddressId"] != DBNull.Value)
 {
     visitingAddress = new Address()
     {
         AddressId = Convert.ToInt64(reader["VisitingAddressId"]),
         Address1 = reader["VisitingAddress"].ToString(),
         AddressType = AddressType.VisitingAddress,
         PostalCode = reader["VisitingPostal"].ToString(),
         PostalDistrict = reader["VisitingPostalDistrict"].ToString()
      };
  }

 if (reader["PostalAddressId"] != DBNull.Value)
 {
     postalAddress = new Address()
     {
         AddressId = Convert.ToInt64(reader["PostalAddressId"]),
         Address1 = reader["PostalAddress"].ToString(),
         AddressType = AddressType.PostalAddress,
         PostalCode = reader["PostalPostal"].ToString(),
         PostalDistrict = reader["PostalPostalDistrict"].ToString()
      };
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I have these helper methods in a data service class (you could make them both static):

```
    public T CastDBValue<T>(object value)
    {
        return MapValue<T>(value);
    }   

    internal static T MapValue<T>(object value)
    {
        try
        {
            T result;
            result = value == DBNull.Value ? default(T) : (T)value;
            return result;
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException cex)
        {
            logger.ErrorFormat("Invalid cast while mapping db value '{0}' to type {1}. Error: {2}", value, typeof(T).Name, cex);
            throw new InvalidCastException(string.Format("Invalid cast while mapping db value '{0}' to type {1}. Error: {2}", value, typeof(T).Name, cex.Message));
        }
    }
```

Then in your mapping code, you just do:

```
AddressId = dataService.CastDBValue<int>(reader["AddressId"]));
if (AddressId > 0) { ... }
```

Comment: This was pretty much what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a micro-ORM like Dapper: http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

The multi mapping functionality would eliminate all that boiler plate code.

```
db.Query<Post,Address,Address,Post>("select * from Posts left join Address ... etc", 
 (post,vaddress,paddress) => 
  {
     post.VisitingAddress = vaddress; 
     post.PostalAddress = paddress; 
     return post; 
   });
```

Comment: @KierenJohnstone - I wouldn't really classify Dapper as an ORM. It is much simpler, and can cleanly eliminate the boilerplate code in the OP's sample, without changing the semantics.

Comment: Well, "a simple object mapper for .NET" takes care of the O and the M, "Dapper is a single file you can drop in to your project that will extend your IDbConnection interface" handles the R (ie RDBMS) :)

Comment: @KierenJohnstone - sure, but in practice, the term ORM has come to encompass much more than just mapping relational data to objects. Unit of work, entity lifecycle management, etc. But enough nitpicking :-)

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I guess I was saying that this is one possible answer, but isn't really "the answer"

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to are ORMs, of which there are many.  NHibernate, Entity Framework, even ADO.NET (which you are already using) has support for relational datasets, although in that case you usually have to use a `DataSet` or derived, strongly-typed classes.

Check out the .NET section here for a list:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software

What are you requirements?  Maybe we can narrow it down.

Comment: We are already using EntityFramework but in this specific case we use classic ADO.NET to call a stored procedure. We had some problems to load related objects with entity framework and stored procedures.